# VS 2008 cannot checkin file

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I am getting this error when I am trying to checkin a file in VS 2008
"Microsoft Visual Studio cannot shut down because a modal dialog is active. Close the active dialog and try again." I don't see any modal window. I tried looking in the task manager and their is nothing.

Anybody has any idea?

Thanks
Mithil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the weirdest thing to happen. I have to screens and I recently swapped my screens, making my primary my secondary and vice versa. Apparently when I tried to check in the pop up window ..pop'ed up on the other screen but never showed. I switched my screens back to the original configuration and then tries checking in the file and wahlaa...their it was the pop up showed up. Then i swapped my screen again to the way I wanted it and now the checkin is working fine.

One of those things...MS..:)
Thanks Beth for your suggestion.

Comment: Did exactly the same (switched screens recently) and did not think of the obvious. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

try alt-tab to cycle through the active applications.  let go of the Alt key when you get to VS.

Comment: I tried that too. I can't see any modal window. It is as if it is invisible.

Comment: Done...the modal window does not show up on the screen nor the task manager. It is invisible. :(

Comment: doesn't visual studio show up in task manager?  that's what I meant to kill, the whole thing and then open it up again and start over.

Comment: Yes, that is when the error message pops up if I try to kill it through task manager. Here is what happens. When i check in any file, VS hangs up.I can't click on any thing or do anything. But I can do other stuff out of VS. When I try to kill VS through task manager, that is when the pop up shows up saying I need to close the modal window.

Comment: apparently, you're not alone: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/26c6f09e-594d-45ca-b040-805483243544

Comment: shut the PC down?  or turn it off?  unplug it?